# checking a json object against a schema before CXF converts it to object

Tags: java, json, cxf

I am using Apache cxf and I have developed a simple restful application. I have a function that consumes json object through post method and converts it to a pojo.
I am required to check if the json object is valid against a particular schema. Is it possible that I can put in a hook to do so. My post function is given below.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/json")
public String addProductFromJson(Product p){
    pDao.addProduct(p);
    return "OK"+p;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. One has to implement *messageBodyReader* in a class and do the needful in the *readFrom()*. This class has to be annotated @Provider and @Consumes(mediatype). Also one should make beans.xml file in the WEB-INF directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down a filter or an Interceptor to validate your json payload with schema. You can use Jackson library(there are others as well) to validate that json payload against schema

Comment: Can you point me to a page. I have no idea how to write an interceptor. Also I would like to stay clear of Jaxson if possible

Comment: This could help you - http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/spring-interceptor-example

Comment: or check this out, this  is more simple - http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter